# Asp.net I have to export data in excel

Tags: c#, oracle

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conns); // C#  
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from APPLICATION AND FRAME", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Load(dr);
    grdSeacrhResult.DataSource = dt;
    grdSeacrhResult.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

got error of

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Do you really have a table named "APPLICATION AND FRAME"?

Comment: What should `select * from APPLICATION AND FRAME` do?

Comment: Thats because your sql is not valid, correct it and try again

Comment: i have changed table name still i got thsi error

Answer (score 0):

Once you have sorted your SQL out use Nuget and get closedXML,

then your code should be

```
private void WriteExcelData(string f, DataTable dt, string savePath, string sheetName)
{
using (wb == new XLWorkbook(f)) 
    {
    dynamic ws = wb.Worksheet(sheetName);
    ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dt.AsEnumerable());
    wb.SaveAs(savePath);
}
```

}

or if you want to use the closed XML documentation use this https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adding%20DataTable%20as%20Worksheet&referringTitle=Documentation